# Decimal values in seek bar in Android

Tags: android, decimal, seekbar, android-seekbar

I am working on android application in which i am using seek bar. In which my range is from 0 - 20 and starting value is 5. For numeric values it is working fine, but now i want to make it for decimal values but the range should be from 0.0 to 20.0. My code for numeric is given below:

```
SeekBar seek=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        seek.setProgress(5);
        seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
        textView.setText( progress + " km");// + seekBar.getMax());
        distance = progress;
        }
        });
```

XML for seek bar:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="5 km"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/gray" />
```

I have used this sample code for decimal values but it is not working.

```
SeekBar seek=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        seek.setProgress(5);


        seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {

        double value = ((float)progress / 20.0);
        String yourprogress = String.valueOf(value);
        textView.setText( yourprogress + " km");// + seekBar.getMax());
        distance = (int) value;
        }
        });
```

Comment: and what is the current result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make your progress range from 0 to 200 and then multiply current progress with 0.1f when it changes. Cheers.

```
SeekBar seek=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        seek.setProgress(5 * 10);


        seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {

        float currentProgress = progress * 0.1f;
        String yourprogress = String.format("%.1f", currentProgress);
        textView.setText( yourprogress + " km");// + seekBar.getMax());
        }
        });
```

in your XML layout add this to the progress bar

```
android:max="200"
```

When you want to getProgress also multiply with 0.1f

```
float currentProgress = seekBar.getProgress() * 0.1f;
```

Comment: @Bojab Kseneman thanks for your reply. Can you please provide me a code snippet here according to my condition, it will help me.

Comment: by doing the above snippet it gives me the values like this:  3.000001, 3.1 ---- 4.0000001. 4.1 . And it is also starting from 1 instead of 5Km like in previous time. Please help me out in this.

Comment: I have fixed the code. Sorry, you need to properly format the progress. And you also have to multiply 5 with 10 to be ok